# test it with the platforms using the expo image-picker library

Tags: react-native, expo-image-picker

```js
const pickImage = async () => {
    const { status: cameraStatus } = await ImagePicker.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
    const { status: mediaStatus } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
  
    if (cameraStatus !== 'granted' || mediaStatus !== 'granted') {
      alert('Lo siento, necesitamos permisos para acceder a la cámara y la galería para continuar.');
      return;
    }
  
    Alert.alert(
      'Seleccionar fuente de imagen',
      '¿Desde dónde desea seleccionar la imagen?',
      [
        {
          text: 'Galería',
          onPress: async () => {
            const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
              mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
              allowsEditing: true,
              aspect: [4, 3],
              quality: 1,
            });
  
            if (!result.canceled) {
              setImage(result.assets[0].uri);
            }
          },
        },
        {
          text: 'Cámara',
          onPress: async () => {
            const result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
              mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
              allowsEditing: true,
              aspect: [4, 3],
              quality: 1,
            });
  
            if (!result.canceled) {
              setImage(result.assets[0].uri);
            }
          },
        },
      ],
      { cancelable: true }
    );
  };
```

I have this function that I am using the expo image-picker library, it works fine it selects the images from the gallery or camera but the problem I have is that if I upload the photo with iOS it doesn't show in android and if I upload it with android it doesn't show in iOS.

How can I fix it?

I have already tried everything but I can not get the solution if someone would know why that happens to me, I'm working with firebase and the uri that I get to the database is the following example:

`file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B83F9F94-B037-4826-BA01-8257644F4BE5/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Fmy-book-app-1538cc5d-94e3-4e10-8427-e56605d7c3f3/ImagePicker/DCA74DD0-FFB8-40A5-8F9E-694B68DD0D1E. png`

I do not know if it has something to do and that the format of both is different.